# Jquery alert box for registrate new user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im all new to ajax and jquery so iam asking u guys for some help. I have to forms that one creates a new user and second logs the user in.
The functions work greate, but i want to create alert boxes for success or failure of the functions.

And i dont know how... Here is my code

HTML

```
  <!-- Formular for signing up -->
  <h4 class="form-headline"> Not a member? Sign up here </h4>


 <form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Username </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newusername"> 
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newpassword"> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Your club </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newclub"> 
    </div>   

   <input type="button" id="btn-reg" class="btn btn-success"      value="Sign up!">
 </form>
```

Script

```
 // -----------------Registration of new user----------------------


 console.log('Script loaded...');

// Calling for the method - reg
  $("#btn-reg").on("click", reg);      

function reg(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Klick, klick...');

    // Declaring variables
    var newusername=$("#newusername").val();
    var newpassword=$("#newpassword").val();
    var newclub=$("#newclub").val();



            $.post('classCalling.php', {

                    newusername: newusername,
                    newpassword: newpassword,
                    newclub: newclub
                },
                 function(data){
                        console.log(data);

                    });
            }
```

PHP

```
                // Creating instance of the class userClass.php


            var_dump($_POST);

            if(isset($_POST['newusername'])){   


                // Defining variables
                $newusername = $_POST['newusername'];
                $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
                $newclub = $_POST['newclub'];

                // Password hash
                $hashpassword = sha1($newpassword);

                $user = new User();     
                $user->newUsers($newusername, $hashpassword, $newclub);


                } else {

                }?>
```

OOP

```
    // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Function for saving new user to database 
    public function newUsers($newusername, $hashpassword, $newclub) {

        // Using prepared statement to prevent mysql injections.
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,  password, club)VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $newusername, $hashpassword,  $newclub);

        if($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "<h3 class='usercreated'>Created</h3>";
            } else {
                echo "<h3 class='usercreated'> Failed </h3>";
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that you are using function to create a new user, my bad again

```
    if(isset($_POST['newusername'])){   
            // Defining variables
            $newusername = $_POST['newusername'];
            $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
            $newclub = $_POST['newclub'];

            // Password hash
            $hashpassword = sha1($newpassword);

            $user = new User();     
            $status = $user->newUsers($newusername, $hashpassword, $newclub);
            if($status) {
                echo json_encode(array("status" : "success"));
            }else {
                echo json_encode(array("status" : "failed"));
            }
    }
```

Make a return from this function

```
 public function newUsers($newusername, $hashpassword, $newclub) {
    // Using prepared statement to prevent mysql injections.
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,  password, club)VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $newusername, $hashpassword,  $newclub);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false
    }
 }
```

this will be the same

```
       $.post('classCalling.php', {

                newusername: newusername,
                newpassword: newpassword,
                newclub: newclub
            },
             function(data){
                var object = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(object.status);
                // or you can add if else by using the status
             });
        }
```

Comment: Hmm it gives me this error  `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')` for the line echo json_encode(array("status" : "success"));

Comment: Oops sorry my bad it should be 

`array("status" => "success");`

confusing between javascript and php syntax :P

Comment: It worked better but now im getting this wierd error in my Console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a               VM14749

Comment: sorry just changed something above, i didn't notice that the function called from another file

Answer (score 0):

You could just echo the script tag.

```
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "<h3 class='usercreated'>Created</h3>";
        echo "<script type="text/javascript">";
        echo "alert("Hello World!")";
        echo "</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<h3 class='usercreated'> Failed </h3>";
        echo "<script type="text/javascript">";
        echo "alert("Hello World!")";
        echo "</script>";
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For the Script block.

```
var posting = $.post('classCalling.php', {
     newusername: newusername,
     newpassword: newpassword,
     newclub: newclub
});
posting.done(function( data ) {
     alert( "Data Loaded Ok");
}); 
posting.fail(function( data ) {
     alert( "Error loading data");
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry, but that gives me back Data loaded ok, even if my user registration failed

Comment: You must to throw an exception in php side, when login fails. For example throw an 404 when username dont exists.

Comment: Also when username exists but the password is incorrect, then throws an 401 exception.